# Example of set A with measure zero such that $\bar{A} = \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Example of a set A that has measure zero such that $\bar{A} = \mathbb{R}$.

I can think of sets that have measure zero such as $\mathbb{N, Q}$, or the cantor set.

I also know that a subset of a set of measure zero has measure zero.

I just can't figure out what the probable notation of $\bar{A}$ signifies.

Is it the complement of A or the supremum or subset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol $A^-$ or $\overline{A}$ denotes the **closure** of a set. That is,
$$ \forall x \in A^-, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists y \in A\mid |x - y| < \epsilon
$$
If $A^- = \mathbb{R}$, then $A$ is **dense** in $\mathbb{R}$. An example would be the collection of rational numbers.